# Upload image and get "URL Only" in text field

Tags: file-uploads, image

In EE1 part of our workflow was to upload images and store just the path to them in the a text field.  Sometimes this images were uploaded in the control panel and sometimes when there were dozens of them they were uploaded via SFTP.

When we uploaded through the control panel we used the "URL Only" option.[image]

EE2 introduced the File Field type which is a nice feature BUT they also took away the ability to get "URL Only" on upload.  `/images/folder/imagename.png`

In my limited use of EE 2.8.1 when you upload an image you can only get the whole image tag `<img src="/images/folder/imagename.png">` AND you can only get the image to appear in a textarea not in a text field.

Am I overlooking something? Is there a way to recover the former functionality?

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen the image tag pair - https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/custom_fields.html#variable-pair-usage

If you're using a File field you have all the parameters and variables you need including options to output path, full URL, description, image manipulation, credit, date and so on.

Comment: Shit, I totally forgot about that. A great solution.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not - you'll have to place the link to the file in the field, then remove the extraneous markup manually.

The only real solution here is to use [Assets](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/assets).

Comment: Thanks Derek.  Can you confirm that what I'm seeing with textarea vs text fields is true?  I can only get the img tag to appear in textarea fields. So on channels that do not have any textarea fields there is not even a workaround!